# How do I create a dictionary from a list with the keys being an iterated number?

Tags: python, python-3.9

I want to make a dictionary where the key numbers the values, based on the size of the list.

For example, I want to use the languages list;

```
languages = [Albanian, Arabic, Russian, Spanish]
```

and take that to create (and print) a dictionary that looks like:

```
print (worldLanguages)
```

Desired Output:

```
1: Albanian
2: Arabic
3: Russian
4: Spanish
#etc, etc
```

My list is going to grow to around 60 elements long, so using a loop to count the numbers of languages in the list makes sense.  Just not sure how to go about getting the integer from the loop into a dictionary's key.

Using Python 3.9.5.

Comment: `dct = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(languages, 1)}`

Comment: You are looking for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `dict` with `enumerate` with start value of 1 for your case.

```py
>>> dict(enumerate(languages, 1))

{1: 'Albanian', 2: 'Arabic', 3: 'Russian', 4: 'Spanish'}
```

Comment: Perfecto!  I'm brand spanking new to this so I'm still learning all the vocabulary used.  Thanks!  This is so much easier than what I was trying to do with a `for` loop.

Comment: @Xiong, using for loop is also fine, it's just that this code is shorter and is more readable and utilizes the enumerate builtin.